# Why are there blank spaces in the Unicode character table and how do I check if a unicode value is one of those?

Tags: python, unicode

If you check out the [Unicode Table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character), there are several spaces further in the table that are simply blank. There's a unicode value, but no character, ex. U+0BA5. Why are there these empty places?

Second of all, how would I check if a unicode value is one of these empty spaces? My code determines a unicode value using unichr(int), which returns a valid unicode value, but I don't know how to check if this unicode value will simply appear as an empty box.

Comment: You can use the `unicodedata` module to determine if a code point is assigned.

Comment: [U+0BA5](https://codepoints.net/U+0BA5) has not been assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Unicode codepoints have received an assignment; this can be for any number of reasons, historical, practical, policital, etc. The full range of values between 0 and 10FFFF are Unicode codepoints but are not necessarily assigned a character or a name.

You could test if a given codepoint has a Unicode *name*, by using the [`unicodedata.name()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name); it'll raise a `ValueError` when a codepoint has no name assigned to it:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\u0BA5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
```

It'll depend on exactly what you want to skip if that suffices. For example, the control codes at the start of the Unicode table you referenced don't have names, but *are* assigned a specific purpose.

Every Unicode codepoint also has a *general category*, a two-letter code that tells you what the codepoint is meant for. The [`unicodedata.category()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) gives you that category:

```
>>> unicodedata.category('\u0BA5')
'Cn'
```

The Cn category is the *Other, not assigned* category.

It depends on what specifically you need to do with the character. There are codepoints that don't have a name but have meaning, such as the control codes (category Cc) or are there for very specific purposes other than display text (such as the surrogate codepoints, or the formatting codepoints, categories Cs and Cf, respectively), or are reserved for future use (Co). As such you may want to exclude *all* C* category codepoints:

```
unicodedata.category(codepoint)[0] == "C"
```

Last, but not least, the  Unicode standard is updated regularly, and codepoints that fall under the Cn category in older versions of the standard have received assignments in newer. New minor Python releases (the second digit in the Python version, so 3.7, 3.8, etc.) will generally include the most recent Unicode standard version at the time of their release. Check the [`unicodedata.unidata_version` attribute](https://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version) for what specific version of the standard was bundled.

Comment: This yields false positives. The exact solution is `not_assigned = unicodedata.category(u'\u0BA5') == 'Cn'`.

Comment: @DanD.: depends on your needs; I've added a section on categories. For the implied use case of the question, ignoring *all* C\* categories would be warranted.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only works by coincidence.

There are code points that have no name but which are assigned. For example in 5.2.0, `unicodedata.name(u'\u0000')` errors. But it is assigned. As the NUL character has the Unicode category Cc.

To test for unassigned code points, test if the category is `'Cn'`:

```
unicodedata.category(u'\u0BA5') == 'Cn'
```

This evaluates to `True` meaning that it is not assigned.

Comment: There are 145.717 unnamed codepoints that are **not** in the Cn category (which contains 836.602 codepoints). There are different use-cases for either test.

Comment: Most of those are *private use* codepoints, Co. Then there are 65 Control Codes (Cc), such as 0000, the surrogate codepoints (D800-DFFF) and a over 6k Lo (Letter, other) codepoints that are unnamed. It depends on your specific use case if testing for the name or for the specific category is needed.